# Local Dim vs. Static variable

Tags: vb.net, performance, il

> From the **IL** perspective, what are the main differences (performance wise) between a local **Dim** variable and a local  **Static** variable?

I've always thought that [Dim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ee5a7s1.aspx) would allocate storage space every time, whilst [Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx) would allocate storage space only once, hence faster. But as you can see below, this is not the case.

- **A:** *Dim*
- **B:** *Static*

[image: Chart]

```
Public Class Form1

    Public Sub New()
        Me.InitializeComponent()
        Dim b As New Button() With {.Text = "Run", .Height = 30, .Location = New Point(10, 10)}
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Me.Run
        Me.Controls.Add(b)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Run(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Dim count As Integer = 10000
        Dim watch As New Stopwatch()
        Dim list As New Test(Of Control)(count)
        Dim last As Control = list.Items(count - 1)
        Dim a, b As Double, i As Integer

        For i = 1 To 10000
            watch.Restart()
            list.IndexOfA(last)
            a += watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
        Next

        For i = 1 To 10000
            watch.Restart()
            list.IndexOfB(last)
            b += watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
        Next

        watch.Stop()
        Array.ForEach(Of Control)(list.Items, Sub(c As Control) c.Dispose())
        list = Nothing

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A: {0}{1}B: {2}", a.ToString("F4"), Environment.NewLine, b.ToString("F4")))

    End Sub

    Public Class Test(Of T As {Class, New})

        Public Sub New(count)
            If (count < 0) Then Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count")
            Dim items As T() = New T(count - 1) {}
            For index As Integer = (count - 1) To 0 Step -1
                items(index) = New T()
            Next
            Me.Items = items
        End Sub

        Public Function IndexOfA(item As T) As Integer
            Dim index As Integer
            Dim length As Integer
            Dim item2 As T
            length = (Me.Items.Length - 1)
            For index = 0 To length
                item2 = Me.Items(index)
                If (item2 Is item) Then
                    Return index
                End If
            Next
            Return -1
        End Function

        Public Function IndexOfB(item As T) As Integer
            Static index As Integer
            Static length As Integer
            Static item2 As T
            length = (Me.Items.Length - 1)
            For index = 0 To length
                item2 = Me.Items(index)
                If (item2 Is item) Then
                    Return index
                End If
            Next
            Return -1
        End Function

        Public ReadOnly Items As T()

    End Class

End Class
```

**Edit**

As per comment, I've edited the code so it don't *"restart the stopwatch at every loop iteration".*

```
watch.Start()
For i = 1 To 10000
    list.IndexOfA(last)
Next
watch.Stop()
a = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds

watch.Restart()
For i = 1 To 10000 
    list.IndexOfB(last)
Next
watch.Stop()
b = watch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds
```

The results are almost the same:

- **A:** 358,3624
- **B:** 538.8570

Comment: Research how static and local variables are implemented on the CLR.

Comment: You restart the stopwatch at every loop iteration. Time measurement is inaccurate for very short time periods. Better start it before the loop and stop it after the loop.

Comment: @usr Could you provide a link?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I could but I'd only link to Google. There are quite a few great posts on CLR internals.

Comment: @usr Yeah, no need to do that. You see, I'm not familiar with CLR, so this might sound stupid/simple to you. But for me, it's a genuine question;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå what I'm saying is that this is a duplicate question. No doubt that it is genuine on your part. If you're interested in CLR internals there's a lot of material.

Comment: @usr My apologies, and I appreciate your comments.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes My bad, it should be `Restart`.

Comment: Using *Static* suppresses a jitter optimization that can keep the storage for a variable in a CPU register.  Relevant because another thread *could* observe changes to these values.  It doesn't in your case but there's nothing that the jitter can do to be sure of that.  Memory is slow, that's why it takes longer.

Comment: I always love your thoughts @HansPassant, thanks! I don't know why you deleted your answer, but the part about `instantiated` and `not instantiated` sounded interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference in performance is not how the variables are allocated, it's in how they are accessed.

Local variables are allocated on the stack, which takes no time at all. Literally. The allocation is done by moving the stack pointer, and that is done anyway to create a stack frame for the method, so allocating local variables doesn't take any more time.

Static variables in an instance method are allocated as part of the data for the class, and that is done only once in this case. Allocating another variable only means that more data is allocated, so that doesn't increase the time.

Accessing the variables is a different story. A local variable is accessed by addressing part of the stack frame, which is easy. A static variable on the other hand is accessed by getting a pointer to the static data of the class, and then addressing the variable at an offset from that. That means that every access to a static variable needs a few more instructions.

Comment: Yes, and local variables can be optimized by the use of CPU registers instead of stack space, which makes them even more efficient.

Comment: Local static variables are allocated per-instance if they occur within an instance method and as part of the static data if they occur within a static method. You can easily test this.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: That makes no difference, as there is only one instance.

Comment: @Guffa: My comment was regarding your statement that "static variables are allocated as part of the static data for the class" - this clearly only applies to VB local static variables within Shared methods, not instance methods.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: You may be right about that detail, but it still has no relevance for the question.

Comment: @Guffa (and others) I really appreciate your answers and comments. I'll give you a +1. But if you don't mind I'll keep this question open for a while (not days - and as I'm not familiar with CLR) and let the community have its say.

Answer (score -2):

VB local static variables are allocated once per instance if they occur within an instance method.  They are only allocated once overall if they occur within a Shared method.

Comment: To the downvoter: The information I provided is correct - please explain the down vote.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but while your answer is correct, it does not give an answer to the question. It does not explain the observed difference in the timing.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I'm not the downvoter neither, and I appreciate your answer. But from MSDN: _"When you declare a static variable in a procedure that isn't Shared, only one copy of the variable is available for each instance of the class."_ And as you can see in my code, I'm only creating one instance of `Test<T>` once.